# Extract first two integers as they appear in string c++

Tags: c++, regex, string-parsing

I have a basic question regarding removing integers from a c++ string. I'm not particularly familiar with c++ or too good with regular expressions.

I have a string such as

```
string myString = "12 text 345 text"
```

The integers can be of any length and the text as well (it is not fixed). What i need to do is extract the first integer (12) and the second one (345) into two separate integer objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stringstream` as follows:

```
 std::string myString = "12 text 345 text";
 int firstInteger = 0;
 int secondInteger = 0;
 std::string firstString= "";
 std:string secondString="";

 std::stringstream ss(myString);
 ss >> firstInteger >> firstString >> secondInteger >> secondString;
 std::cout << "firstInteger " << firstInteger 
      << "\nSecondInteger " << secondInteger <<std::endl;
```

It outputs:

```
 firstInteger 12
 secondInteger 345
```

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
stringstream os(myString);
os >> int imp1 >> string dummy >> int imp2;

cout << imp1 << " and " << imp2;
```